# User Input not Printing below text

Tags: loops, system, sleep, do-while

Im trying to have text that writes slowly then use a do-while loop, but when I run the code I get: enter text below >: when it should be like: enter text below with the :> below that, I've tried changing it from print to println but nothings working. I need some help

public class Quick_Time_Event_Base_Code {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //  Creates a quick time event where if the player doesn't input the right command
    //  then you "Fail" but if you input the correct code, you break out of the loop and "Pass"
    String message = "Enter Text Below";
    char[] chars = message.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(chars[i]);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
        System.out.println("  >: ");
        System.out.flush();     
        String pass = input.nextLine();
        if (pass.equals("Example Input Here")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(" You Failed the Quick Time Event");
        System.exit(0);
    } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//[...]
char[] chars = message.toCharArray();
     for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(chars[i]);
         Thread.sleep(100);
     }
System.out.println("");


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("  >: ");
//[...]
```

Try it like this. 
If you finish the loop, you will jump to the next line.